# Converter imagem para base64 com IonicFramework

Tags: ionic, conversão, base64

Existe alguma biblioteca que permita converter imagens para `base64` com o *Ionic Framework*?

Tentei utilizar o [angular-base64-upload](https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload), funcionou com o angular, porém no *Ionic* não obtive sucesso.

Se alguém conhecer alguma biblioteca ficaria muito agradecido, ou mesmo alguma forma nativa de fazer a conversão.

*Observações:*

- Quero pegar a imagem carregada tanto da camera com o plugin do *Cordova*, como também da galeria de imagens do *Android*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neste caso você usa um plugin do ngCordova chamado câmera porém com alguns atributos diferentes no qual esta abaixo.

```
$scope.abrirGaleria = function () {
    var options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });
  }
```